# IO Exception : the process is being used by another process zip file

Tags: c#, .net-core

Hi I used zipfile for compressing directory in a .NetCore web api and I for doing my process I have a directory with these details:

```
C:\Parsa\1\1.mp4
C:\Parsa\1\image\1.jpg
```

I used this:

```
ZipFile.CreateDirectory("C:\\Parsa\\1","C:\\Parsa\\1.zip");
```

I get this exception type:

> "C:\Parsa\1\image\1.jpg" cannot be accessed because it being used by
>   another process.

And files in the directory would be compressed but files in subdirectory of that directory would not be compressed. 
What is the problem?

Comment: And what does that error tell you? The most likely cause, is you forgot to dispose of the filestream or something if you were touching that file, if you haven't been playing with it, then someone else has an open handle to it. Could be another app, another thread, or even a virus scanner, or another application

Comment: "another process" in that error message is frequently misleading. In almost all cases (that lead to a question being asked on SO), the "other process" turns out to be your own. Have you done anything else to interact with that file before this point, and if so, have you correctly cleaned up after yourself there?

Answer (score 0):

The file `C:\Parsa\1\image\1.jpg` is opened in another program. Maybe you opened the file with a image viewer?

Or you opened the file programatically without closing it again.

If you don't find the program, which has the file open, then restart your computer.